# Fatal error: Uncaught /journal/storage/vendor/twig/twig/src/Loader/ArrayLoader.php | opencart3.6

Tags: opencart-3

I have installed Opencart 3.0.3.6 and I am trying to install journal3 and it gives fatal error on homepage.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Twig\Error\LoaderError: Template "journal3/template/journal3/product_card.twig" is not defined in "journal3/template/journal3/module/products.twig" at line 8. in /home/huf3m3f0ml55/public_html/journal/storage/vendor/twig/twig/src/Loader/ArrayLoader.php:70 Stack trace: #0 /home/huf3m3f0ml55/public_html/journal/storage/vendor/twig/twig/src/Environment.php(299): Twig\Loader\ArrayLoader->getCacheKey('journal3/templa...') #1 /home/huf3m3f0ml55/public_html/journal/storage/vendor/twig/twig/src/Environment.php(381): Twig\Environment->getTemplateClass('journal3/templa...') #2 /home/huf3m3f0ml55/public_html/journal/storage/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(333): Twig\Environment->loadTemplate('journal3/templa...', NULL) #3 /home/huf3m3f0ml55/public_html/journal/storage/cache/template/ea/ea68dc69c47734ed0c15134e87131363619d771da3973aecb2062097ad9de43f.php(392): Twig\Template->loadTemplate('journal3/templa...', 'journal3/templa...', 8) #4 /home/huf3m3f0ml55/public_html/journal/storage/vendor/twig/twig/src/Extens in /home/huf3m3f0ml55/public_html/journal/storage/vendor/twig/twig/src/Loader/ArrayLoader.php on line 70
```

Please help me with the mentioned issue.
I don't know if the problem is in the template files or in the vendor folder.

Comment: Because the Journal theme is very complicated and does not meet Opencart standards, and the theme is paid, it is better to send a support ticket to the Journal developers.